# comments not visible on all computers (facebook comments)

Tags: asp.net, facebook

Please i have problem in facebook comments module,
There is a difference in the comments offered by a pc to another pc or from Facebook account to another account Facebook
Where some of the comments that appear and some do not, and in another's account shows other comments.

```
        <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/ar_AR/all.js#appId=myappid&amp;xfbml=1"></script>

    <fb:comments width="550" notify="true" migrated="1"></fb:comments>
    <br />
    <%--    <p><fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button></p>--%>
       <p><fb:like></fb:like></p>
    <div id="fb-root">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({ appId: 'myappid', status: true, cookie: true,
                xfbml: true
            });

//            FB.Event.subscribe('comments.create', function (response) {
//                // do something with response.session
//                alert("add comment");
//            });
            FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function (response) {
                //alert(response.commentID);
            });   

            FB.Event.subscribe('comment.remove', function (response) {
                // do something with response.session
                alert("thank you for remove comment");
            });

        };

        (function () {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.type = 'text/javascript';
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/ar_Ar/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);


        } ());
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is a feature of the comment box. Basically, Facebook shows what it thinks is most interesting for you. It internally weighs comments by poster activity, your own profile, and those of your "friends."

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/:

> Social Relevance: Comments Box uses social signals to surface the highest quality comments for each user. Comments are ordered to show users the most relevant comments from friends, friends of friends, and the most liked or active discussion threads, while comments marked as spam are hidden from view.